# How to create checkbox with getJson

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please i will be happy to get help on how to display checkbox along with my data returned with getJSON as shown in the image

[image: image of how i want]

Below is the code of my ajax/getJSON:

```
           $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"clsAddCart.php",
                data:dataString,
                cache: false,
                success:function(data){
                 // $("#display_info").html("Item Added Successfully");

                    //display cart data

                    var url="clsGetCartData.php";
                    $.getJSON(url,'transID='+$('#transID').val(),
                        function(result)
                        {
                            $("#answer tbody").empty();
                            var alltrans=result["alldata"]; //get the list
                            for( i in alltrans)
                            {
                                var cartdata=alltrans[i];   //get
                                var cartID=cartdata["cartID"];
                                var partName=cartdata["partName"];
                                var qty=cartdata["qty"];
                                var productID=cartdata["productID"];
                                var Sellprice=cartdata["Sellprice"];
                                var Discount=cartdata["Discount"];
                                var Total=cartdata["Total"];
                                var myid="<input type='checkbox' name='uid[]' value = 1>";//=cartdata["myid"];
                                var myDel=Document.createElement("input");
                                myDel.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
                                myDel.setAttribute('name','DelItem');
                                myDel.setAttribute('value',cartdata["cartID"]);
                                var htmlCode="<tr id='"+productID+"'>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+myid+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+cartID+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+partName+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+Sellprice+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+qty+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+Discount+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+Total+"</td>";
                                htmlCode+="<td>"+ document.body.appendChild(myDel);+"</td>";
                                /* htmlCode+="<td>"+qty+"</td>";
                                 htmlCode+="<td>"+Sellprice+"</td>";*/
                                htmlCode+="</tr>";
                                $("#answer tbody").append(htmlCode);
                            } //end for loop

                            $("#answer tr").click(function()
                                {
                                    dataSelected($(this).attr("id"));
                                }
                            );

                        } //end success callback function
                    ); //end method call to getJSON
```

It shows and error

> (Uncaught TypeError: Document.createElement is not a function)

I will be very happy to receive your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
htmlCode+="<td>"+ document.body.appendChild(myDel);+"</td>";
```

By

```
htmlCode+='<td><input type="checkbox" id="delete'+myid+'" name="delete'+myid+'" value=""></td>';
```

Comment: Hello Naincy, am grateful you got back!!

Comment: I replaced the code as you suggested but the check box is not created along with the data